# Convert selected cells formula to value across Selected Sheets

Tags: excel, vba, selection

I'm using this code below to convert formula to cells, which works fine in a single sheet. But the problem is when I need to convert all selected cells which are in different sheets to their value, this code doesn't do it.

This is how I am selecting the cells in Excel:
first I select the cells in one sheet, than I go down to the tabs right-click and select specific sheets, which in Excel selects the corresponding cells in every selected sheet.

So any tips on how I can change this code to make it work across different sheets?

```
Sub formulaToValues()
    If Selection.Cells.Count = 1 Then
        Selection.Value = Selection.Value
        Selection.Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = 0
        Selection.Cells.Font.Color = vbBlack
    Else
        For Each cel In Selection.Cells
            cel.Value = cel.Value
            Selection.Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = 0
            Selection.Cells.Font.Color = vbBlack
        Next cel
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Are the cells always in the same location on each sheet?

Comment: Does every worksheet in the workbook need to be formatted or only those selected?

Comment: @K.Dᴀᴠɪs yes, they are always in the same location

Comment: @rohrl77 I would prefer only those selected

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that you wanted selected sheets - I updated your question and my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to just grab the address of the selection, then add that to each worksheet's range

```
Sub formulaToValues()

    Dim celAddr As String
    celAddr = Selection.Address

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets
        With ws.Range(celAddr)
            .Value = .Value
            .Interior.ColorIndex = 0
            .Font.Color = vbBlack
        End With
    Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: `.value = .value` is not required?

Comment: No, it would be the same thing as saying `Apple = Apple` - only because the origination range is the same as the destination range..---- Scratch that, I see that he was using a formula - thanks for pointing that out, edit coming soon.

Comment: @K.Dᴀᴠɪs If there are sheets in the workbook that don't need to be changed, then this doesn't work. Neither does my answer for that matter.

Comment: @rohrl77 The question does state _"and select all sheets, which in excel selects the corresponding cells in every sheet"_, so I think we are both correct. And the title: _"... across all sheets"_

Comment: @K.Dᴀᴠɪs OH! Ok. I updated my answer to take only those that are selected... which was interesting to learn. I'll just include both versions.

Comment: @K.Dᴀᴠɪs Thanks Davis, never thought of approaching it by capturing the address, but I forgot to mention that I am selecting multiple cells in one sheet, and with this code all the cell values are converted into the same one.

Comment: Hmm. What do you mean all the cell values are converted into the same one? It only updated the cells I selected. Just be careful making changes with all your worksheets selected because those changes will happen on all of them simultaneously. @CKCCN

Comment: for instance, I selected three formula cells in my sheet, and when execute this macro, the second and third cell value becomes the value of the first cell and not its own converted value. and thanks for the heads up.

Comment: @CKCCN Very strange, I still cannot reproduce your issue. I wonder if the dependency changes due to a cell's value being changed. I don't know any other explanation - but if this was the case, you could add `application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual` to the top of the sub and change it back to `= xlCalculationAutomatic` at the end.

Answer (score 1):

You are attempting to write to a 3D cell collection. An interesting problem i haven't seen before. I gave it a shot.

The below code works for me. I have simply added an extra loop to search through any other sheets. Note: it is good practice to always declare your variables.

Answer1: This cycles through every sheet in the workbook

```
Sub formulaToValues()
Dim cel As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet
If Selection.Cells.Count = 1 Then
    Selection.Value = Selection.Value
    Selection.Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = 0
    Selection.Cells.Font.Color = vbBlack
Else
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        For Each cel In Selection.Cells
            ws.Range(cel.Address).Value = 2 'cel.Value
            Selection.Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = 0
            Selection.Cells.Font.Color = vbBlack
        Next cel
    Next ws
End If

End Sub
```

Answer2: With this one it only goes throug the selected sheets

```
Sub formulaToValues()
Dim cel As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet
If Selection.Cells.Count = 1 Then
    Selection.Value = Selection.Value
    Selection.Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = 0
    Selection.Cells.Font.Color = vbBlack
Else
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Windows(1).SelectedSheets
        For Each cel In Selection.Cells
            ws.Range(cel.Address).Value = 2 'cel.Value
            Selection.Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = 0
            Selection.Cells.Font.Color = vbBlack
        Next cel
    Next ws
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I actually did try to loop through the workbook too but I am too newb and couldn't get it to work, guess some mistakes was there with mine. And in my case this did the job for me. Thanks for this.

Comment: Hi CKCCN, glad to help. It was an interesting problem to see. One that i had not thought about before.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks alot guys, this got answered pretty quickly.
I am placing my macros in personal so I ended if with this

```
Sub formulaToValues3()
Dim cel As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet
If Selection.Cells.Count = 1 Then
Selection.Value = Selection.Value
Selection.Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = 0
Selection.Cells.Font.Color = vbBlack
Else
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Windows(1).SelectedSheets
    For Each cel In Selection.Cells
        ws.Range(cel.Address).Value = ws.Range(cel.Address).Value 'cel.Value
        Selection.Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = 0
        Selection.Cells.Font.Color = vbBlack
    Next cel
Next ws
End If

End Sub
```